# jmathplot doesn't work in swing application

Tags: java, swing, plot, jpanel, jmathplot

I'm trying to use the [jmathplot](https://code.google.com/p/jmathplot/) library in a swing application.

Problem is, it doesn't seem to work when I add it to a JPanel as follows:

```
    // create your PlotPanel (you can use it as a JPanel)
    double[] x = new double[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    double[] y = new double[] { 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16 };


    // create your PlotPanel (you can use it as a JPanel)
    Plot2DPanel graph = new Plot2DPanel();
    graph.setBounds(0, 0, 782, 272);

    // add a line plot to the PlotPanel
    graph.addLinePlot("my plot", x, y);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(10, 333, 782, 272);
    tab_analysis.add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.add(graph);
```

Because the plot doesn't show up and I get weird axes as well:

[image]

The site states:

`use the PlotPanel as any Swing component (all PlotPanel extends JPanel, in fact)`

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- works with `NullLayout`, without any issue, but I'm quite not familair with this layout manager (delegate `Insets` from parent), then I'm leaving any comments about
- simple don't to use `NullLayout`
- override `getPreferredSize` for `Plot2DPanel`
- `JPanel` has `FLowLayout` (with the same output as from `NullLayout`! on resize), accepting only `PreferredSize`, child aren't resizable with its contianer, is required to use `BorderLayout`/`GridLayout` for simple graph

.

[image]
 .

[image]

.

from code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import org.math.plot.Plot2DPanel;

public class MyPlot {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("JMathPlot library in a swing application.");
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public MyPlot() {
        double[] x = new double[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        double[] y = new double[]{10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16};
        Plot2DPanel plot = new Plot2DPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(400, 200);
            }
        };
        plot.addLinePlot("my plot", x, y); // add a line plot to the PlotPanel
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(plot);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MyPlot();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense! What a small but important detail! Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 you are welcome, note there are alyways two ways you can to a) read docs b) debug instets/set/preferredSize after setVisible(true)

Comment: I tried a) but couldn't find anything. Never done b) so thank you for teaching me.

Answer (score 1):

You can see here examples if you want Jean-Paul:

http://jmathtools.berlios.de/doku.php?id=jmathplot:tutorial

Comment: But all those examples are in an independent (popup) jFrame, not in another frame.